# How to load RediSearch module in Redis stack server installed using docker

Tags: docker, makefile, redisearch, redis-stack-server

i installed Redis Stack Server using this command using docker

```
docker run -d --name redis-stack-server -p 6379:6379 redis/redis-stack-server:latest
```

but when i am trying to use the redis-cli on the terminal to see the modules using MODULE LIST it shows an empty array.
Then i tried to use the github repository using the make commands to add the redisearch.so file to the module list but i encountered this error:

```
# readies version: 185fd0d
brew list curl &>/dev/null || brew install curl
brew list wget &>/dev/null || brew install wget
Error: Cannot install under Rosetta 2 in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)!
To rerun under ARM use:
    arch -arm64 brew install ...
To install under x86_64, install Homebrew into /usr/local.
command failed: brew list wget &>/dev/null || brew install wget

In /Users/garimaminocha/chatgpt/RediSearch/sbin/setup:
18          python3 -m pip list
19       fi
20       
21   >>> $ROOT/sbin/system-setup.py
22       if [[ $VERBOSE == 1 ]]; then
23          python3 -m pip list
24       fi

make: *** [Makefile:379: setup] Error 1
```

I want to use ft.create and ft.search for a project that uses this database. what have i done wrong?
(if this comes across as a stupid question - I have never worked with databases before and i am just starting out in compsci, i really appreciate the time taken to read and help me out.)

I tried to install using docker and the github repository. the rest is explained above.

Comment: Hi Garima!  Welcome to stackoverflow!  To improve your question, can you provide the exact `redis-cli` command you used, as well as the output?  Let's see if stackoverflow  users can help get that working.  Building from scratch is an option, but that is a different problem.

Comment: Hi there - I suspect you might have another instance of regular Redis running too and that it's grabbed port 6379.  Try looking for instances of a process called `redis-server` and stopping those, then start your Redis Stack container.